# get text in between text using regex

Tags: regex

I want to extract the text in between the %3A.

Here is the sample phrase :

```
http://www.sample.com/res?ccode=1232&note=sampletext&token=12Add-12sre-24Aod-23343-34kdi%3A3232121%3ATVLOPQUI%3AIOOPDA%3AKKKKK%3A&ltr=23232
```

I tried below expression:

```
[&]{1}token[=]{1}([a-zA-Z0-9-%]*)(%3A(.*?)%3A){1}
```

but the expected phrase is : **3232121**

whereas, it is capturing the invalid thing.

Can you please suggest me, how to do that in better way

Comment: Are you limited to just regex here?

Comment: Thanks for reply Wikitor, yes there is no option here. I have to use regex

Comment: Something like: `(?<=%3A|:)(\d+)`?

Comment: Thanks for reply hd, it didn't match to my requirement

Comment: Which flavour of regex are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are no literal `&` inside the params, you may use the following pattern:

```
[&?]token=[^&%]*%3A([^%&]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKonBu/1)

**Details**:

- `[&?]token=` - a `&token=` or `?token=` substring
- `[^&%]*` -  zero or more chars other than `&` and `%`
- `%3A` - a `%3A` substring
- `([^%&]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more chars other than `%` and `&`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for quick help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to find `%3A`, then match all digits after that.

```
(?<=%3A|:)(\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/IHaXQT/4